# Javascript regex or substring to get if block content?

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I am looking for regex or substring of javascript to achieve the following task in an efficient way. Suppose my input is

```
if(browser=="IE7"){
    if(check=="false"){
        ...
        console.log(something);
        console.log(something1);
        ...
         }
 }
 else {
        console.log(somethigelse);
 }
```

Output should be:

```
if(check=="false"){
    ...
    console.log(something);
    console.log(something1);
    ...
}
```

What I have tried is basic one like below which is just a string without any new line charcters.

```
var some="if(browser=='IE7'){console.log(IE7)}else{console.log(FF)}"
console.log(some.substring(some.indexOf("if(browser=='IE7'){")+19, some.indexOf("}")));
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: What I wrote is the basic one like below `var some="if(browser==IE7){console.log(IE7)}else{console.log(FF)}"
console.log(some.substring(some.indexOf("if(browser==IE7){")+17, some.indexOf("}")));` which does not have any new lines.

Comment: Add the code to your question.. not to a comment, where it does little good.  Also, aside from being invalid syntax, which seems to be a mistake to me, you don't explain why the first if is not included in the string.

Comment: I should note; I'm not going to fix your mistakes, given they may be apart of the original question, so if they aren't, please do so yourself.

Comment: The invalid syntax is still present as of your edit; is it supposed to be there?  The `{` present in the first if?

Comment: fixed it, can you please check now..

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have a `+19` after the first search?  Remove that, and add a +1 to the end, it works in a basic sense, though it would likely trip up for nested ifs.  Let me think a moment.  You also have not explained why the first if isn't included in the results.

Comment: Do you want to get all the "if" blocks or do you want the "if" block within the "if(brower=="IE7")" block only?

Comment: The real problem is that I need to get browser specific code from a javascript file i.e if condition is there for IE7 I need get the snippet of code which is inside of that if block..I hope I am not confusing you

Comment: I want all the code inside of "if(brower=="IE7")"  block, it could have many nested if blocks or some snippet of code..

Comment: Please update your sample text to be more representative of the actual edge cases you're looking to encounter.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This routine will capture the desired text inside the brackets regardless of nesting.

**JavaScript Code**

```
 /*jshint multistr: true */
 var sourcestring = 'if(browser=="IE7"){ \
    if(check=="false"){ \
        ... \
        console.log(something); \
        console.log(something1); \
        ... \
         } \
 } \
 else { \
        console.log(somethigelse); \
 }';

  var i = 0;
  var splitstring = sourcestring.split(/([{}])/);
  var Output;
  var blnInside = false;
  var DepthCount = 0;
  var FoundDepth = 0;
  var DesiredRegex = /if\(browser=="IE7"\)/ig;

  for (i = 0; i < splitstring.length; i ++) {

    // if this is a close bracket, decrease the depth
    // this is first to prevent close brackets form being processed if they are the outer most bracket around the desired text
    if (splitstring[i] == "}") {
        DepthCount --;
    }

    // if you're inside and more deep then matching text then process the line
    if (blnInside && DepthCount > FoundDepth) {
        print ("line " + i + " is inside " +splitstring[i]);    
    } 

    // if this is an open bracket, then increase the depth
    if (splitstring[i] == "{") {
        DepthCount ++;
    }

    // if the current depth falls below the found depth then you are no longer inside
    if (DepthCount <= FoundDepth ) { 
        blnInside = false;
    }

    // set blnInside to true if the this has the desired text
    if (DesiredRegex.exec(splitstring[i]) && !blnInside) {
        FoundDepth = DepthCount;
        blnInside = true;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
line 2 is inside      if(check=="false")
line 3 is inside {
line 4 is inside          ...         console.log(something);         console.log(something1);         ...          
line 5 is inside }
line 6 is inside
```